# rsync faliure on iscsi disk

Tags: rsync, iscsi

```
[root@localhost ~]# rsync -aHXA /mnt/capture-tmp/source/ /mnt/capture-tmp/dest
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4092 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on "/mnt/capture-tmp/dest/opt/StorageManager/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so": Read-only file system (30)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(302) [receiver=3.0.7]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (135188 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

"dest" is iscsi disk.I am not able to reason out the cause for the faliure??
Thank you.

Comment: What type of destination filesystem? Some FSes will go read-only if I/O times out. What does "mount" say about your destination before and after this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seems obvious enough:

```
rsync: write failed on "[...snip...]/libjvm.so": Read-only file system (30)
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Remount it as read/write and try again.

Comment: same procedure is failing for this particular machine....for other machine it works fine....

Comment: also it does not fail immediately.It fails after some transfer is done.